# Angular linking from View 2 to View 1 without page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my angular app working with routing and two views.

When on the second view I am simply trying to add a link back to view 1 i.e "Back to home"

I tried the following and it works ofcourse, but it's acting like a normal href and refreshing the page

```
<a href="/">Back to Search</a>
```

How do I add a link without the full page refresh but just change the views ?

EDIT ADDED Routing Config

```
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
      controller : 'SearchCtrl'
    })
    .when('/result',{
      templateUrl: '/views/result.html',
      controller : 'resultCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo : '/'
    });
}]);
```

Comment: what is written for ("/") in your route provider/state provider ?

Comment: You need to handle this condition as well in you route provider .when options

Comment: Looks like I have to add it like this "<a href="#/">" to stop the full refresh when im back in the root..is this normal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using HTML5 mode or not. But first you need to set up your homepage to "/".

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
        etc....
    })
```

After this you can link to your homepage using

```
<a href="#">
```

Comment: Tried just the "#" still does a full page refresh

Comment: @StevieB Are you sure that you don't have any conflicting code somewhere else? I'm pretty sure this should work

Comment: I added my routing to original post, but yup still doing full refresh

Comment: I got it working by changing my link to following <a href="#/">Back Home</a> kinda weird ?

Comment: @StevieB Yep.. I wouldn't know why that happens, should work without, and I also find it weird when you use 'href="#"' that your otherwise doesn't catch the link